# Runing sample program "hello world" in NICE Programming language in ubuntu?

Tags: nice-language

I have a program written in NICE language below:

```
void main (String[] args)
{
// your code goes here
print("Hello World!");
}
```

I have installed **nicec** utility to compile it in ubuntu, but unable to compile it.

Can any one can help me to run it from my ubuntu machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why exactly do you tag this as Java ?

Comment: It is documented here: http://nice.sourceforge.net/compilation.html. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I tried but couldn't.

Comment: so what did you try, and what was the result you got?

Comment: It is giving the following error on executing the following command:
nicec --sourcepath=~/nice my.program
nice.lang: parsing

Command line:
Package my.program is not available.
The source  path is: ~/nice
The package path is: .
compilation failed with 1 error

Comment: Pay attention when adding tags to your questions. Exactly none of the ones you've selected actually apply here.